# Checking if any date in a python list of dates is between two date columns

Tags: python, pandas, date, pyspark

I have a dataframe with two columns. One is a START_DATE and one is an END_DATE. I also have a python list of dates. I want a third column in the dataframe that indicates if any of the dates in my python list falls between the START_DATE and END_DATE in the dataframe for each particular row. If there is a date in the dates list between the START_DATE and END_DATE, the third column should show true.

```
dates_list = ['2019-01-06', '2019-04-08']

START_DATE|END_DATE|
____________________
2019-01-01|2019-01-12
2019-01-03|2019-01-05
2019-04-03|2019-04-09
```

I want a third column showing

```
TRUE
FALSE
TRUE
```

It would be great to have in pyspark, but pandas works too.

Comment: And what did you try so far?

Comment: I haven't thought of anything that could do it. merge_asof is a thought. .between() also seemed promising, but it takes scalars, not columns.

Comment: Is `START_DATE` sorted? that info may be useful

Answer (score 3):

This could be done using [`pd.IntervalIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.html). Let's start by converting all dates to datetime:

```
from datetime import datetime
df = df.apply(pd.to_datetime)
dates = [datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d') for x in dates_list]
```

Now let's build a `pd.IntervalIndex` using its [`from_arrays`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.from_arrays.html) method, and check which intervals contain [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) date from the list using a list comprehension:

```
ix = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df['START_DATE'],df['END_DATE'],closed='both')
[any(date in i for date in dates) for i in ix]
# [True, False, True]
```

Comment: This looks good. My problem is that this is a very large file--I don't think that a double for loop is possible.

Comment: I've been playing around with interval indices and couldn't find a more straight forward way @wbarts

Answer (score 1):

try using [pd.date_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) and intersection techniques of set to check date exist or not

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"start_date":["2019-01-01","2019-01-03","2019-04-03"],
                       "end_date":["2019-01-12","2019-01-05","2019-04-09"]})
dates_list = ['2019-01-06', '2019-04-08']
```

```
def creating_dates(row,date_list):
    dates = list(pd.date_range(start=row['start_date'], end=row['end_date']).astype(str))
    res = set(dates).intersection(set(date_list))
    if res:
        return True
    return False
```

```
df['check_exist'] = df.apply(lambda x:creating_dates(x,dates_list),axis=1)
```

```
   start_date   end_date    check_exist
0   2019-01-01  2019-01-12  True
1   2019-01-03  2019-01-05  False
2   2019-04-03  2019-04-09  True
```

Answer (score 1):

Sine you tagged **pyspark**, you can probably try [pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join):

### Setup

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

>>> df.show()
+-------------------+-------------------+
|         START_DATE|           END_DATE|
+-------------------+-------------------+
|2019-01-01 00:00:00|2019-01-12 00:00:00|
|2019-01-03 00:00:00|2019-01-05 00:00:00|
|2019-04-03 00:00:00|2019-04-09 00:00:00|
+-------------------+-------------------+

>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- START_DATE: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- END_DATE: timestamp (nullable = true)

# Convert List of Dates into a spark dataframe
dates_list = ['2019-01-06', '2019-04-08']
df_dates = spark.createDataFrame([(d,) for d in dates_list], ['date'])
df_dates = df_dates.withColumn('date', F.to_timestamp('date'))

>>> df_dates.show()
+-------------------+
|               date|
+-------------------+
|2019-01-06 00:00:00|
|2019-04-08 00:00:00|
+-------------------+
```

### Join (left_semi, left_anti) and then Union

Use left_semi Join to get all matched Rows and left_anti JOIN to get all non-matched Rows, flag the Rows and then Union the results

```
df_new = df.join(df_dates,
            (df_dates.date <= df.END_DATE) & (df_dates.date >= df.START_DATE)
          , how='left_semi'
    ).withColumn('Flag', F.lit(True)
).union(
         df.join(df_dates,
            (df_dates.date <= df.END_DATE) & (df_dates.date >= df.START_DATE)
          , how='left_anti'
    ).withColumn('Flag', F.lit(False))
)

>>> df_new.show()
+-------------------+-------------------+-----+
|         START_DATE|           END_DATE| Flag|
+-------------------+-------------------+-----+
|2019-01-01 00:00:00|2019-01-12 00:00:00| true|
|2019-04-03 00:00:00|2019-04-09 00:00:00| true|
|2019-01-03 00:00:00|2019-01-05 00:00:00|false|
+-------------------+-------------------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

I am still relatively new at python but thought i would have a go :)

hope it helps!

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

dict = {'START_DATE':['2019-01-01','2019-01-03','2019-04-03'],
        'END_DATE': ['2019-01-12','2019-01-05','2019-04-09'],
        'RESULT':['FALSE','FALSE','FALSE']}


dates_list = ['2019-01-06', '2019-04-08']

df = pd.DataFrame(dict)

print('BEFORE')
print(df)


for row in df.itertuples():

    start_date = datetime.fromisoformat(df.at[row.Index, 'START_DATE'])
    end_date = datetime.fromisoformat(df.at[row.Index, 'END_DATE'])     
    result = 'false'

    for datestr in dates_list:
        date = datetime.fromisoformat(datestr)

        if start_date <= date <= end_date:
            result = 'TRUE'
            df.at[row.Index, 'RESULT'] = result


print('AFTER')
print(df)
```

Will give you

**Output**

```
BEFORE
   START_DATE    END_DATE RESULT
0  2019-01-01  2019-01-12  FALSE
1  2019-01-03  2019-01-05  FALSE
2  2019-04-03  2019-04-09  FALSE
AFTER
   START_DATE    END_DATE RESULT
0  2019-01-01  2019-01-12   TRUE
1  2019-01-03  2019-01-05  FALSE
2  2019-04-03  2019-04-09   TRUE
```

Comment: this works but still uses a double nested for loop.